# Android color background transition like css

Tags: android, css, android-activity, background-color

I need make the background color of my activity little bit different ( programatically ) i have this example in css:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
   div{
       width: 150px;
       height: 150px;
       background-color: #343;
       transition: ease all 0.5s;
   }
   div:hover{
       background-color: #ccc;
   }    
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x199ax41/ ( please hover the div ), someone know how could i do the same effect when user click in a button for example?

This is a bad idea ( thinking usability )?

Thanks.

Comment: using jquery `toggleClass` you can easily achieve that.

Comment: Do you mean this? http://jsfiddle.net/x199ax41/2/ (Click it)

Comment: Or this? http://jsfiddle.net/x199ax41/3/

Comment: With JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/x199ax41/4/

Comment: May be [this](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/x199ax41/5/) is you are looking for

Comment: May be this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19260401/change-background-on-button-click-using-css-only) will help you.